# Best practice of counter in map struct golang

Tags: go, go-map

I have a code that is not clean. I want to increment `Counter` in struct of `NameLike` but I think this is not effective.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type NameLike struct {
    Name    string
    Counter int
}

func main() {
    sosmed := make(map[string]NameLike)

    sosmed["rizal"] = NameLike{"Rizal Arfiyan", 10}

    for i := 1; i < 10; i++ {
        sosmed["rizal"] = NameLike{
            Counter: sosmed["rizal"].Counter + 1,
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(sosmed)
}
```

do you have any ideas regarding this code, to make it clean?

```
sosmed["rizal"] = NameLike{
    Counter: sosmed["rizal"].Counter + 1,
}
```

This link for [Golang Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/S0SlIrsGJ3V)

Comment: Why not just `sosmed["rizal"].Counter++`?

Comment: i have tried it but it have error "cannot assign to struct field sosmed["rizal"].Counter in map"

Comment: Ah, yea, because it's not addressable. Let me type up a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few approaches you could take to simplify this code.

The current map passes `NameLike` by *value*. If you pass by reference, you can simplify things a bit:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type NameLike struct {
    Name    string
    Counter int
}

func main() {
    sosmed := make(map[string]*NameLike)
    sosmed["rizal"] = &NameLike{"Rizal Arfiyan", 10}

    for i := 1; i < 10; i++ {
    sosmed["rizal"].Counter++
    }

    fmt.Println(sosmed["rizal"])
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/-xvCJyqQ6V0

Comment: thank you for helping me